# Concentrix matrix of 0 and 1

Tags: arrays, matrix

I have created a program to generate the alternate squares of 0 and 1 but it's not showing the expected output. Pls help.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
public class LEDLights {

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                
                int size;
                
                  System.out.println("Enter the size of an array:");
                  Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
                  size=sc.nextInt();
                  System.out.println("Enter the array elements:");
                int myarr[][]=new int[size][size];    
                         for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                            {
                                
                                
                                for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                                {
                                    myarr[i][j]=sc.nextInt();
                                    
                                }
                            }
                         System.out.println("Status of the lights");
                         for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                            {
                                
                                
                                for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                                {
                                
                                    System.out.print( myarr[i][j]+ " ");
                                    
                                }
                                System.out.println();
                            }    
                         
                         
                          //int n=5;
                        
                        //printing the outer loop   
                            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                            {
                                
                                
                                for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                                {
                                
                                    
                                    if(i==0 || i==size-1 || j==0 || j==size-1)
                                    myarr[i][j]=1;
                                }   
                            }
                    //  inner loops of 1
                        //  int p=size;
                            for(int p=size-3;p>=size/2;p-=2) {
                            for(int t =2 ; t <=size/2; t+=2)
                                {
                              // int p=size-3;
                                //while(p>=size/2) {
                            
                                    for(int i = t; i <=p; i++)
                                    {
                                        
                                        
                                        for(int j = t; j <=p; j++)
                                        {
                                        
                                    
                                            
                                            if(i==t || i==p || j==t || j==p)
                                            myarr[i][j]=1;
                                        }   
                                    }
                                }
                                //p-=2;
                                
                        }
                    
                            
//      inner loops of 0
                            
                            for(int k =1 ; k <size/2; k+=2)
                            {
                                for(int p=size-2;p>size/2;p-=2) {
                            for(int i = k; i <=p; i++)
                            {
                                
                                
                                for(int j = k; j <=p; j++)
                                {
                                
                            
                                    
                                    if(i==k || i==p || j==k || j==p)
                                    myarr[i][j]=0;
                                }   
                            }   
                        
                            }
                            }
                            
                            System.out.println("LED lights blinking\n");
                            
                            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                            {
                                
                                
                                for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                                {
                                
                                    System.out.print( myarr[i][j]+ " ");
                                    
                                }
                                System.out.println();
                            }   
                            
            }


}
```

**expected output for 8*8**

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 
1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 
1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 
1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: Can you explain how your algorithm works?

Comment: This has been asked before. IMO the simplest way to do it is to look at each square in turn, compute the distance to the nearest edge and depending on whether the distance is odd or even set 0 or 1.

Comment: It prints the outer loop of 1 first. Then for printing 0, it starts from index 1 incrementing it with 2 for the next square. The same is the case for 1, it starts from index 2. The program continues until the innermost circle is achieved. My logic can be incorrect in a program. I want to achieve the result for any matrix with size >=4. See the output for 8*8 .

Comment: Hi @Rup, can you provide the running code or any link available for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class LEDLights {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the size of an array:");
        int size = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter the outer status of light. Either 0 or 1");
        int startPoint = sc.nextInt();

        int[][] myarr = new int[size][size];

        myarr = updateArr(myarr, 0, size, startPoint);

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                System.out.print(myarr[i][j] + " ");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private static int[][] updateArr(int[][] myarr, int startsize, int endsize, int startPoint) {

        if (startsize > endsize)
            return myarr;
        for (int i = startsize; i < endsize; i++)
            for (int j = startsize; j < endsize; j++)
                myarr[i][j] = startPoint;
        return updateArr(myarr, startsize + 1, endsize - 1, (startPoint == 0) ? 1 : 0);
    }
}
```

This gives you an alternate code but will be doing more iterations

Comment: I am taking the binary array as an input and I want to print 0 and I based on logical AND and OR operation. How can we modify this code? @Harshavardhan Konakanchi

Comment: @Pooja on what basis you want to the Logical AND / OR ?

Comment: Instead of writing 0's and 1's directly, I want to generate them based on input array elements e.g 1 AND 0=0, 0 AND 0=0, 1 OR 1=1 and 0 OR 1=1.

Comment: @Pooja My question is with what element you want to do ? You want to do between adjacent, diagonally, row or column wise or two different matrices ?

Comment: The output generated by your program is correct. The thing is I want to accept a binary N*N array from a user and want to generate the squares by doing the logical operation with each element of an array. If we want to generate a square of 1's we will  be doing OR 1 operation with each element of an array, same is the case for 0- AND 0 with each element. I don't want my program to check the element of previous square and creating the next square based on it.